# SVG: Masking a pattern on a <circle>

Tags: html, svg

Trying to get a pinstripe-like effect ontop of a circle with a filled color, so that the pattern is masked on top of the circle. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, but my code seems close to what would be correct.

```html
  <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
  <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="200" width="200">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="stripe" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10">
        <g >
          <line x1="10" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" />
        </g>
      </pattern>
      <mask id="mask" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="ObjectBoundingBox">
        <rect height="300" width="300" style="fill: url(#pinstripe);" />
      </mask>
      <style>
        g {
          mask: url(#mask);
          stroke: black;
          stroke-width: 1px;
          stroke-linecap: butt;
          stroke-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
        circle {
          fill: green;
        }
      </style>
    </defs>
    <g>
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
    </g>
  </svg>
```

You can look to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffGK3/) to effectively see nothing - to actually view the circle, remove the `mask: url(#mask);` style.

So I'm not quite sure what's wrong - I'm just trying to have a circle with a green fill and white stripes on top. Any help would be seriously appreciated!

Comment: The "rect" style has url(#pinstripe) but it should probably be "url(#stripe)"

Comment: You're right! Thanks, but that doesn't quite fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to fix your "white" and "black" color because that's what's used in a mask.

Here's an example that works (of your code). Try switching the "white" and "black" colors in the "fill" and "stroke" attributes.

**Here's my first example with a "rect":**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="200" width="200">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pinstripe" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="white" />
  </pattern>
    <mask id="mask" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="ObjectBoundingBox">
      <rect x="0.5" y="0.2" height="300" width="300" style="fill: url(#pinstripe)" />
    </mask>
    <style>
      g {
        mask: url(#mask);
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 1px;
        stroke-linecap: butt;
        stroke-rendering: crispEdges;
      }
      circle {
        fill: green;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**EDIT:**

**Here's another version using line (notice that I'm setting fill and stroke to "#ffffff" or "white" to make this mask:**
​

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="200" width="200">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="pinstripe" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10">

            <line x1="10" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#ffffff" />
      </pattern>
        <mask id="mask" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="ObjectBoundingBox">
          <rect x="0.5" y="0.2" height="300" width="300" style="fill: url(#pinstripe)" />
        </mask>
        <style>
          g {
            mask: url(#mask);
            stroke: black;
            stroke-width: 1px;
            stroke-linecap: butt;
            stroke-rendering: crispEdges;
          }
          circle {
            fill: green;
          }
        </style>
      </defs>
      <g>
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
      </g>
    </svg>​
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much for your help. unfortunately, I'm particularly looking for white stripes on a green background. That is - the circle is still filled green, but the pattern would be white stripes across it.

Comment: Updated my answer to make it green with white stripes

Comment: You're awesome and that is perfect. Thanks so much for your help. A final, slightly associated question: how might I make it such that the stroke-width of the pattern is 2 and there's no separation between the lines? Image: ![stripes](http://cl.ly/image/1C2B1E0Y1I2B)